# ERC20 amount exceeds allowance in tests solidity

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, smart-contract-wallets

I'm trying to transfer balance from one account to another, but whenever I try I get the following feedback...

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance -- Reason given: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance.
```

I'm trying to do this action via frontend (solidity test unit).

Below I put my files.

My file test.js

```
contract("Token721", (accounts) => {    
    let [alice, bob, cain, dan] = accounts;
    let contractInstance;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        coinInstance = await TokenCoin.deployed();                   
        contractInstance = await Token721.deployed();              
    });
     
    describe("deploy Heroes", async () => {
        it("transfer founds from alice to bob", async () => {
            await coinInstance.transfer(bob, web3.utils.toWei("550", "ether"));
            let totalBob  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(bob);

            assert.equal(web3.utils.fromWei(totalBob.toString()), "550");
        })
        it("invoke a new hero", async () => {
            let totalBob  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(bob);
            console.log("TOTAL BOB "+web3.utils.fromWei(totalBob.toString()));
            
           const hero = await contractInstance.invokeRandomHero(bob, 
                'https://myurl.com/heroes/8356281049284737', cain, {from: bob, gas: 3000000});
            // const uri = await hero.tokenURI();        

            totalBob  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(bob);
            console.log("TOTAL BOB "+web3.utils.fromWei(totalBob.toString()));

            let totalCain  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(bob);
            console.log("TOTAL CAIN "+web3.utils.fromWei(totalCain.toString()));
        });
        xit("total heroes created is equals 1", async () => {
            const total = await contractInstance.totalHeroes();
            assert.equal(total.toString(), "1");
        });
    });
})
```

My file ERC721.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Token721 is Ownable, ERC721URIStorage {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
  
  //event para novos hero invocados
  event CreatedNewHero(uint heroId, string uri);
  //TEST COIN
  address coin;
  uint amountInvoke = 300;
 
  constructor(address _coin) ERC721("Token721", "SAKH") {
    coin = _coin;
  }

  function setCoin(address _coin) public{
    coin = _coin;
  }

  function invokeRandomHero(address _player, string memory _tokenURI, address _recepient) public returns (uint){
    //CHECK IF EXISTS COINS
    IERC20 tokenA = IERC20(coin);
    uint _total = tokenA.balanceOf(_player);

    if(_total < amountInvoke)
      revert("No Founds");
      
    tokenA.transferFrom(_player, _recepient, 300);

    _tokenIds.increment();

    uint256 newHeroId = _tokenIds.current();
    _mint(_player, newHeroId);
    _setTokenURI(newHeroId, _tokenURI);

    // emit CreatedNewHero(newHeroId, _tokenURI); 

    return newHeroId;       
  }

  function totalHeroes() public view returns(uint){
    return _tokenIds.current();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumming that the `TokenCoin` contract is an ERC20 you need to call `approve` before attempting a transfer. and also you need to run the `TokenCoin` contract as alice to with the `connect` method.

It will look like this:

```
it("transfer founds from alice to bob", async () => {
        await coinInstance.connect(alice).approve(bob, web3.utils.toWei("550", "ether"));
        await coinInstance.connect(alice).transfer(bob, web3.utils.toWei("550", "ether"));
        let totalBob  = await coinInstance.balanceOf(bob);

        assert.equal(web3.utils.fromWei(totalBob.toString()), "550");
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..
I would like to use transfer inside the invokeRandomHero method, would it be possible? Or not?

Comment: You can, as long as you do the approve first outside of the function

Comment: I tried this: 
``` lang-js
await coinInstance.connect(alice).approve(cain, web3.utils.toWei("550", "ether"), {from: bob})
            const hero = await contractInstance.invokeRandomHero(bob, 
                'https://myurl.com/heroes/8356281049284737', cain, {from: bob, gas: 3000000});
```
but I'm having the error saying:
``` TypeError: coinInstance.connect is not a function```